# How to display AWS S3 Bucket media objects in Angular using Django API

Tags: django, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-status-code-403

I am using a Django (PostgreSQL) Backend for my application. On my frontend, I am using Angular. I have an API view that is used to retrieve Post model instances where each instance has a "media" field containing an image object stored in an Amazon S3 Bucket. On my Angular frontend, I am trying to display the S3 Bucket media image using the  src attribute and setting it to the URL of the image in the bucket, however, I am getting a 403 forbidden error.

Below are my configurations. What am I missing that is causing the 403 Forbidden error?

I have the following setting configurations in my Djnaog settings.py:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_REGION_NAME = config('AWS_REGION_NAME')

# Set the S3 bucket name you created earlier
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

# Set the S3 URL format
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'

# Set the S3 file URL access
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

# Set the S3 storage class
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'StorageClass': 'STANDARD_IA'}

# Set the static and media file configurations
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

# To serve media files directly from S3
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/media/'
```

On my frontend, I have the following Angular `ng service`:

```
getUserFeed(token: string): Observable<any> {
    const feedUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/feed';

    // Set the headers with the Authorization token
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
    });

    return this.http.get(feedUrl, { headers, withCredentials: true });
  }
```

I make the following call in my component's typescript file:

```
this.userService.getUserFeed(token).subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
          this.feedData = response.results; // Store the feed data in the property
        }
```

The returned data provides a results array where each result item has the following field:

```
media: "https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.jpg"
```

Then in my HTML, I have:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of feedData">
            <img [src]="item.media" />
        </div>
```

However, my browser console returns the error:

```
GET https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.jpg 403 (Forbidden)
```

I set up the following Bucket policies:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::socialpy-media-s3/*"
        },
    ]
}
```

And I have the following CORS policy:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost:4200"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

And I unblocked the following bucket setting:

```
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket or access point policies
```

Comment: I unblocked the following bucket setting:
```Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies```
And now it works. However, now the images are accessible anywhere, not just through my website. If I just paste the link in my browser I can see the image

Is there a better approach to follow so that it is only accessible through my website?